# Use my Delphi app with Android Auto or iOS CarPlay?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, android-auto, carplay

I have an FMX app written in Delphi 11 Alexandria.

I've been searching for a while to see if it is possible with FireMonkey to use my app in a car (Android Auto or iOS CarPlay), but I didn't find any documentations, examples, or discussions about it.

Is this possible?

Comment: There's an import for the [CarPlay iOS framework here](https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri/blob/master/API/DW.iOSapi.CarPlay.pas), but don't know of any code using it yet. There's bound to be a number of examples in Swift (and perhaps Objective-C), but of course you'd need to translate them into Delphi

Comment: [Convert any Android API to Delphi and C++ Builder units to utilize in your FireMonkey Android Projects](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/convert-any-android-api-to-delphi-and-c-builder-units-to-utilize-in-your-firemonkey-android-projects/).

Comment: For Android, are you referring to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps)? If so, you might want to watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELeNmFrm4vM). Depending on which parts you need to implement (and it could be all of them), you will need to write some Java code, specifically to create the CarAppService descendant, as this part cannot be done in Delphi. Implementing all this makes CarPlay on iOS look like a picnic